# xpath expression issue in mule

Tags: xml, xpath, mule, esb

I've an xml payload that returns to me

```
<response><row><row _id="1" _uuid="CD07C40E-4943-44B0-BF5E-370DA2133E25" _position="1"   
 _address="http://data.seattle.gov/resource/fire-911/1"><type> --T::00</type></row><row _id="111"  
 _uuid="2423EC44-56D5-494C-941F-6F3B5DF49AC5" _position="111"  
 _address="http://data.seattle.gov/resource/fire-911/111"><address>10049 College Way N</address> 
 <type>Aid Response</type><latitude>47.701756</latitude><longitude>-122.335022</longitude>
 <report_location latitude="47.701756" longitude="-122.335022"/>
 <incident_number>F110104009</incident_number></row>
```

I want to capture the "row" nodes with xpath : `#[xpath://response/row/row]`. This returns me a string of commas `[, , , , , , , ,]` instead of

```
<row _id="111" _uuid="2423EC44-56D5-494C-941F-6F3B5DF49AC5" _position="111" _address="http://data.seattle.gov/resource/fire-911/111">
    <address>10049 College Way N</address> 
    <type>Aid Response</type>
    <latitude>47.701756</latitude>
    <longitude>-122.335022</longitude>
    <report_location latitude="47.701756" longitude="-122.335022"/>
    <incident_number>F110104009</incident_number>
</row>
```

If I insert this xpath through an online tester, this works: `//response/row/row`

```
<row _id="112" _uuid="DDAE5717-4A07-4E71-9CAE-D1F1CBAA94FD" _position="112"  _address="http://data.seattle.gov/resource/fire-911/112">
    <address>5929 Beach Dr Sw</address>  
    <type>Aid Response</type>
    <latitude>47.550431</latitude>
    <longitude>-122.397816</longitude> 
    <report_location latitude="47.550431" longitude="-122.397816"/>
    <incident_number>F110104008</incident_number>
</row>
```

What would I have to do get it to work in mule?

My configuration.xml:

```
    <flow name="seattleemergencyFlow1" doc:name="seattleemergencyFlow1">
    <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8900"   
    path="get-emergency" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="data.seattle.gov" port="80" 
     path="resource/kzjm-xkqj.xml?" method="GET" contentType="application/json" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <object-to-string-transformer doc:name="Object to String"/>
    <logger message="#[xpath://response/row/row]" level="ERROR" doc:name="Logger"/>
```

Thank you!

Comment: tip: put four spaces before code blocks to enable syntax highlighting. I tried editing your question but you reverted it.

Comment: What Mule version are you using?

Comment: Hi David, I believe the latest:         Anypoint Studio - Tooling for Mule ESB

Anypoint Studio July 2014 Release
Build Id: 201407311443

Comment: I'm still looking into this. I notice that the XML example you provide is not valid: it's missing `</row></response>` at the end to be valid. Is it a copy/paste issue or are you actually dealing with broken XML inputs (yes this happens IRL :))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're on Mule >= 3.3.x, you should be using MEL instead of the old `xpath:` expression evaluator.

With MEL:

- if you want to get a `java.util.List` of `org.dom4j.Element`, use:

  ```
  #[xpath('//response/row/row')]
  ```
- if you just want the first `org.dom4j.Element`, use:

  ```
  #[xpath('//response/row/row')[0]]
  ```
- if you want to get a `java.lang.String` representation of this element, use:

  ```
  #[xpath('//response/row/row')[0].asXML()]
  ```